# Extremely low energy photons from electron hopping within an energy band

Tags: solid-state-physics

From wikipedia:

> Since the number of atoms in a macroscopic piece of solid is a very large number (N~10^22) the number of orbitals is very large and thus they are very closely spaced in energy (of the order of 10^−22 eV)

My question is then, can an electron hop between these closedly packed energy levels to emit a photon of energy equal to 10^-22 eV ? Or conversely can it absorb such a photon?